# Durandal add button with click event dynamically

Tags: knockout.js, durandal

I have a `knockout` application implemented using `Durandal`. Now On click event of the `Add` button, I want to add `anchor` tag dynamically and by clicking it, a function should be called.

In below code I have a `deleteRowRenderer` function which is called when pressing **Add** button (available in my view.html) and renders `Delete` anchor successfully on my HTML.

Now when I press Delete button, It gives below error message:

> RemoveRecord is not defined

I tried below code:

```
    define([
        "jquery",
        "underscore",
        "knockout"
    ], function (
        $, _, ko) {

        "use strict";

        function MyViewModel() {
            var self = this;

            this.RemoveRecord = function (index) {
                alert('Remove at ' + index);
            }

            this.DeleteRowRenderer = function (params) {
                var html = '<a title="Remove" href="javascript:" class="align-center btn-link btn-sm" onclick="RemoveRecord(' + params + ')">Delete</a>';
                return html;
            }

           this.addRow = function(){
             $('#myId').append(self.DeleteRowRenderer(1));
           }


        }

        $.extend(AgGridViewModel.prototype, {
            activate: function (settings) {
                // Code To BIND DATA With View
            },
            canactivate: function () {
            },
            binding: function () {
            },
            attached: function () {
            }
        });

        return MyViewModel;

    });
```

**HTML**

```
<button data-bind="click: addRow"></button>
<div id="myId"></div>
```

Comment: Where is your view code that calls it?

Comment: That's a plain html with Knockout bindings.

Comment: Yes can you show us your view code

Comment: @LiverpoolOwen: I have added HTML Code.

Comment: Where is you button for removing the record? I am trying to figure out if you are in the wrong context

Comment: The whole point of using knockout is to avoid jquery append like you have done. It's not clear, what exactly you are trying to do. Do you want to add a new row with a remove button on click of `addRow`? [Then you can check this example from the documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html#example-2-live-example-with-addremove). What is `AgGridViewModel`?

Comment: @adiga: This is just a sample code as I cannot put a whole code over here as it is a large code. Just to give you overview, I am using third party grid (which is not supporting knockout features) control to bind grid and in that grid, I want to add action button dynamically and by clicking that action button a javascript function should be called.

Comment: have you considered using [koGrid](https://knockout-contrib.github.io/KoGrid/#/overview)

Comment: @LiverpoolOwen: I want to add remove button dynamically when user clicks on Add button. In the code you can see, click event of the add button calls function `DeleteRowRenderer` which returns `anchor` tag in form of string. I load that string inside div called `myId`.

Comment: There are some limitations for not using koGrid. We are using `AG-Grid` because it is highly customizable.